# Crawling web page links through Visaul Basic 2008

Tags: regex, dictionary, web-crawler

I have tried to convert one of my Visual Basic 6 programs to Visual Basic.NET. This program basically crawls email and mobile number data from a web page link. This program works great in Visual Basic 6 but after converting to Visual Basic.NET is not providing any function or result in .NET.

```
Imports VBScript_RegExp_55
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class autoextratorform
    Dim emailsearch As New ListViewItem()
    Dim numbersearch As New ListViewItem
    Private Declare Function SendMessageByString _
                         Lib "user32" _
                         Alias "SendMessageA" _
                         (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                          ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                          ByVal wParam As Long, _
                          ByVal lParam As String) _
As Long

    Private Const LB_SELECTSTRING = &H18C

    Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
    Private WithEvents cIE As InternetHtml
    Private WithEvents cExtLinks As cExtractLinks
    Private cGSearch As cGoogleSearch
    Dim Excel As Object
    Dim Excelsheet As Object
    Dim a() As String
    Dim b() As String
    Dim c() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    ' Needs reference to Microsoft VBscript Regular Expressions I recomend ver 5.5.
    '
    Dim baseurl As String ' var to store base url so we can build the full path
    Dim dVisited ' Dictionary to hold visited urls = I think Missing here
    Dim dEmail  ' dictionary to hold emails = I think Missing here
    Dim dnumber ' = I think Missing here
    Dim dweb  '= I think Missing here
    ' We are putting the emails in a list also, for user feed back
    'It would be less momery intensive and faster to just keep these in the dictionry object
    'which allows to easily tell if the email already exist
    Dim regxPage ' var to hold regular expression to extract urls
    Dim regxEmail ' var to hold regular expression to extract emails
    Dim regnumber
    Dim regweb
    Dim Match, Matches As String ' we use these to store are regx matches
    Dim Match1, Matches1 As String
    Dim Match2, Matches2 As String
    ' Regular expressions are super powerfull and have been a part of unix for a long time
    ' goto the form load event to see the regex initialization
    '   to learn more about regular expressions and to download the latest scripting runtime see
    '   http://msdn.microsoft.com/scripting/default.htm?/scripting/vbscript/techinfo/vbsdocs.htm
    Dim email, pageurl, mnumber, sweb As String
    ' The above is only because dictionary.exist does not work directly on Match var
    Dim stopcrawl As Integer ' Used to exit crawl loop

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                ListBox2.Items.Clear()
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://classads.jang.com.pk/default.asp?cityid=1")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://www.merapakistan.com/classifieds/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://olx.com.pk/")
                ListBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
                txtStartUrl.Text = ListBox2.Text
            Case 1
                ListBox2.Items.Clear()
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://www.locanto.com.pk/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://pakistanclassifiedads.com/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://pkr.com.pk/")

                txtStartUrl.Text = ListBox2.Text
            Case 2
                ListBox2.Items.Clear()
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://adpost.pk/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://page.com.pk/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://www.clasf.pk/")

                ListBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
                txtStartUrl.Text = ListBox2.Text
            Case 3
                ListBox2.Items.Clear()
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://www.nelaam.com/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://www.asani.com.pk/")
                ListBox2.Items.Add("http://freepost.com.pk/")

                ListBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
                txtStartUrl.Text = ListBox2.Text
              
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
        stopcrawl = 0 ' set stop crawl so we do not exit loop
        If txtStartUrl.Text & "" = "" Then
            lblresult.Text = ("Please Load your Desired Site List !")
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf txtStartUrl.Text & "" = "http://" Then
            lblresult.Text = ("Please Load your Desired Site List  !")
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf txtStartUrl.Text = "" Then
            lblresult.Text = ("Please Load your Desired Site List  !")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' the above should really check for a valid url, but I am a lazy PERL programmer
        ListBox1.Items.Add(txtStartUrl.Text) 'add item to list
        Label16.Text = (ListBox2.Items.Count - 1)
        Label8.Text = (ListBox2.Items.Count)
        lblresult.Text = " Start service for searching Email address and Mobile Numbers"
        Command1.Enabled = False
        ComboBox1.Enabled = False
        LaVolpeButton4.Enabled = True
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: (2064) ComboBox property Combo1.Locked was not upgraded. More Information: https://docs.mobilize.net/vbuc/ewis#2064

        LaVolpeButton8.Enabled = False
        LaVolpeButton9.Enabled = False
        txtStartUrl.ReadOnly = True

        crawl() ' and were off




    End Sub

    Private Sub autoextrator_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        With listnumber

            .Columns.Clear()
            .Columns.Add("Count!", CInt(Width * 0.1))
            .Columns.Add("Mobile Number!", CInt(Width * 0.2))
            .Columns.Add("Web URL!", CInt(Width * 0.68))
        End With
        With listemail

            .Columns.Clear()
            .Columns.Add("Count!", CInt(Width * 0.1))
            .Columns.Add("Email Address!", CInt(Width * 0.2))
            .Columns.Add("Web URL!", CInt(Width * 0.68))
        End With

        'initialize dictionary and regx objects
        dVisited = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dVisited.CompareMode = CompareMethod.Binary
        dEmail = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dEmail.CompareMode = CompareMethod.Binary
        dnumber = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dnumber.CompareMode = CompareMethod.Binary
        dweb = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dweb.CompareMode = CompareMethod.Binary
        Dim counting1 As String
        Dim counting2 As String

        regxPage = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp() ' Create a regular expression.
        regxPage.Pattern = "HREF=""[^""#]+[.][^""#]+" ' Set pattern."
        regxPage.IgnoreCase = True ' Set case insensitivity.
        regxPage.Global = True ' Set global applicability.

        regxEmail = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp() ' Create a regular expression.
        regxEmail.Pattern = "\b[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b" ' Set pattern."
        regxEmail.IgnoreCase = True ' Set case insensitivity.
        regxEmail.Global = True ' Set global applicability.

        regnumber = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp()
        counting1 = "(\+92)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}"
        counting2 = "(?:0092|0|\+92)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}"
        regnumber.Pattern = counting1
        regnumber.Pattern = counting2
        regnumber.IgnoreCase = True
        regnumber.Global = True
        cIE = New InternetHtml()
        cGSearch = New cGoogleSearch()
        cExtLinks = New cExtractLinks()
    End Sub
    Sub crawl()

        While ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 ' loop while list has data
            If stopcrawl = 1 Then GoTo exitcrawl
            getpage(ListBox1.Items(0)) ' This is the heart of the prog, except for the regx = I think Missing here
            ' stuff in the form load event
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(0) ' remove item from list
        End While
        ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedIndex)
        If ListBox2.SelectedIndex < ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 Then
            ListBox2.SelectedIndex += 1
            txtStartUrl.Text = ListBox2.Items.ToString


exitcrawl:
            If ListBox2.Items.Count = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Searching has completed !", "Done ! searching", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                txtStartUrl.ReadOnly = False
                txtStartUrl.Text = ""
                Label3.Text = "-----------------------------------------------------------"
                LaVolpeButton4.Enabled = False
                Command1.Enabled = True
                LaVolpeButton8.Enabled = True
                LaVolpeButton9.Enabled = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub getpage(ByVal page As String)
        On Error Resume Next

        If dVisited.Contains(page) Then

            Exit Sub
        Else
            dVisited.Add(page, 1) ' add page to dVisited dictionary
            Label6.Text = CStr(ListBox1.Items.Count)
            Label14.Text = CStr(dVisited.Count)
            Label3.Text = page
        End If
        baseurl = getpath(page) ' build full url - see getpath
        TextBox1.Text = ""

        If ListBox1.Items.Count > 5000 Then Exit Sub ' sets the maximum cache (so we don't run out of mem)
        Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
            TextBox1.Text = wc.DownloadString(page)
        End Using

        Matches = regxPage.Execute(TextBox1.Text) ' Execute search.
        For Each Me.Match In Matches

            pageurl = Match

            If InStr(1, pageurl, "http://", vbTextCompare) Then
                If dVisited.Exists(pageurl) = False Then ListBox1.Items.Add(Mid(pageurl, 7))
            Else
                If dVisited.Exists(baseurl & Mid(pageurl, 7)) = False Then ListBox1.Items.Add(baseurl & Mid(pageurl, 7))
            End If
        Next

        ' search for email

        Matches = regxEmail.Execute(TextBox1.Text)    ' Execute search.
        For Each Me.Match In Matches     ' Iterate Matches collection.
            ' check if email exist
            email = Match
            Debug.Print(email & dEmail.Exists(email))
            If dEmail.Exists(email) = False Then
                dEmail.Add((email), 1)
                Dim d As Integer
                d = listemail.Items.Count
                d = d + 1

                emailsearch = listemail.Items.Add(d)
                emailsearch.SubItems.Add(email.ToString)
                emailsearch.SubItems.Add(pageurl.ToString)
                ListBox3.Items.Add(email)
                Label10.Text = listemail.Items.Count


            End If
        Next
        Matches1 = regnumber.Execute(TextBox1.Text)
        For Each Me.Match1 In Matches1
            mnumber = Match1
            Debug.Print(mnumber & dnumber.Exists(mnumber))
            If dnumber.Exists(mnumber) = False Then
                dnumber.Add((mnumber), 1)
                Dim c As Integer
                c = listnumber.Items.Count
                c = c + 1

                numbersearch = listnumber.Items.Add(c)
                numbersearch.SubItems.Add(mnumber.ToString)
                numbersearch.SubItems.Add(pageurl.ToString)

                Label12.Text = listnumber.Items.Count
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Function getpath(ByVal URL As String) As String
        ' look for the last / and get a string up to that location
        Dim lastbar As Integer = URL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1
        Dim tmppath As String = URL.Substring(0, Math.Min(lastbar, URL.Length))
        If tmppath = "http://" Then tmppath = URL ' full path already so return url
        Return tmppath
    End Function
    Public Function StripOut(ByVal From As String, ByVal What As String) As String

        Dim result As String = ""
        result = From
        For i As Integer = 1 To Strings.Len(What)
            result = result.Replace(What.Substring(i - 1, Math.Min(1, What.Length - (i - 1))), "")
        Next i

        Return result
    End Function
    Private Sub LaVolpeButton4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LaVolpeButton4.Click
        stopcrawl = 1


        MsgBox(" Service has Stoped by USER !")
        LaVolpeButton4.Enabled = False
        Command1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub LaVolpeButton8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LaVolpeButton8.Click
        Dim strData As String = ""
        Dim strQ() As String
        Dim intFile As Integer

        ' Set up the Common Dialog initial Directory
        ' to the application path. Filter for Text and All files
        ' Prompt the user to select a file
        '
       
        cmd.InitialDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
       
        cmd.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*"
       
        cmd.Title = "Select Email Addresses File"
        cmd.ShowDialog()
       
        If cmd.FileName <> "" Then
            '
            ' If the user selected a file
            ' open and read the entire contents
            ' then split it into records
            '
            intFile = FileSystem.FreeFile()
           
            FileSystem.FileOpen(intFile, cmd.FileName, OpenMode.Input)
            strData = FileSystem.InputString(intFile, FileSystem.LOF(intFile))
            FileSystem.FileClose(intFile)
            strQ = strData.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
            '
            ' Populate the texbox array with the questions
            ' (either the number of textboxes in the control array or
            ' number of questions, which ever is the smaller)
            For Each strQ_item As String In strQ
                ListBox2.Items.Add(strQ_item)
            Next strQ_item
            txtStartUrl.Text = ListBox2.Text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

2- This is Visual basic 6 Code that works perfect.

```
      Dim baseurl As String ' var to store base url so we can build the       full path
     Dim dVisited As Dictionary ' Dictionary to hold visited urls
     Dim dEmail As Dictionary ' dictionary to hold emails
     Dim dnumber As Dictionary
     Dim dweb As Dictionary
    Sub crawl()
  While List1.ListCount > 0 ' loop while list has data
    If stopcrawl = 1 Then GoTo exitcrawl
getpage List1.List(0) ' This is the heart of the prog, except for the   regx
                      ' stuff in the form load event
List1.RemoveItem (0)  ' remove item from list
    Wend
    List2.RemoveItem (List2.ListIndex)
    If List2.ListIndex < List2.ListCount - 1 Then
        List2.ListIndex = List2.ListIndex + 1
   txtStartUrl = List2.Text
   
            Command1_Click
            
    Else
    exitcrawl:
    If List2.ListCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Searching has completed !", vbInformation, "Done ! searching"
    WebBrowser1.Stop
    txtStartUrl.Locked = False
    txtStartUrl.Text = ""
    Label3.Caption =    "-----------------------------------------------------------"
    LaVolpeButton4.Enabled = False
    Command1.Enabled = True
    LaVolpeButton8.Enabled = True
    LaVolpeButton9.Enabled = True
    End If
    End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: Please refer to [mcve]

Comment: I have explained my point in detail so that whoever understands my post can correct my mistake.

Comment: Dim dVisited as dictionary
 Dim dEmail as dictionary ' dictionary to hold emails = I think Missing here